# How to maintain a global variable across site..

Tags: javascript, jquery

My moto: To call a function say XYZ() after gradually increasing time eg.

```
first time after 3 secs, 
second time:6 secs
third time: 12secs
```

This should occur across the pages.. Page A ,B ,C 
Page A first popup then he surfs to page B then the time should increase/doubled up

I know about `setInterval` function.. But i am confused how to work with it ..

1)make a new js and call in master file

2)write a script in all pages.

Comment: use cookie to store value and in js call/update the cookie variable...eg: setInterval('function', cookie_variable*2)

Comment: Use cookies or HTML5 localStorage

Comment: Do you want to increment/double-up the time for every page navigation, or do you want to increment/double-up the time at regular intervals? If you want to do this everytime a page if loaded or an HTTP request is made, then you may not require the use of setInterval.

Comment: any link or snippet to share would be really useful

Comment: not only on another page .. if the user hangs out on same page then also the time should go on increasing ..it shud be maintatined across the pages

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Following code may help you
//using cookie we are handing navigation count

function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    if (parseInt(days, 10)) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        var expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}

// copied from http://lea.verou.me/2009/12/reading-cookies-the-regular-expression-way/
function readCookie(name) {
    name = name.replace(/([.*+?^=!:${}()|[\]\/\\])/g, '\\$1');
    var regex = new RegExp('(?:^|;)\\s?' + name + '=(.*?)(?:;|$)', 'i'), match =     document.cookie.match(regex);
    return match && unescape(match[1]);
}

var navcountval;
if (!readCookie("navcount")) {
    navcountval = 1;
    createCookie("navcount", 1, 365);
} else {
    navcountval = readCookie("navcount");
    navcountval = parseInt(navcountval) + 1;
    createCookie("navcount", navcountval, 365);
}

// your code for of setTimeout based on pagenavcount * seconds like "navcountval * 3sec"
```

Comment: where can i see cookie added?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include this javascript in every webpage and that should achieve what I think you are trying to achieve. This script will double-up the value of 'timeTracker' cookie every 3 seconds

```
function updateInterval() {

    var pageCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    var lastValueOfTimeTracker = 3;

    for(var i=0; i< pageCookies.length; i++) {

        var currentCookie = pageCookies[i].split(',');

        if(currentCookie[0].indexOf('timeTracker') != -1) {
            var temp = currentCookie[0].split('=');
            alert(temp[1]);
            lastValueOfTimeTracker = temp[1];
        }
    }

    document.cookie = 'timeTracker=' + (lastValueOfTimeTracker * 2);        
}
```

Comment: where can i call function here .

Comment: The function will be called automatically on page load, notice the _window.onload_, However, if you don't want it to be like that and you want to call the function explicitly yourself, then all you need to do is, remove the window.onload and wrap the rest of the code inside and function and call it whenever you want want to.

Comment: and i dnt want fixed 3 secs interval.. it shud get doubled after every time called

Comment: I have updated the code snippet, try this, whenever you call this function the cookie should get updated

Comment: I have made one more edit, try this new function, this should definitely work. There was a small bug in my previous edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63276/discussion-between-parth6-and-vaibs-cool).